# error "column count doesnt match value count at row 1" while inserting new values into table

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to add new values to the MySQL database table, but there is always an error. I am new to python programming so I don't really know how all of this works. the photo of the error is below.

```
def add_new():
    eq_name = t1.get()
    total2 = t2.get()
    query = "INSERT INTO Equipment(equipmentID, name, available, borrowed,  total) VALUES(NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW())"
    cursor.execute(query, (eq_name, total2, 0, total2 ))
    clear()
```

[image]

Comment: The problem described in this question doesn't have anything to do with `tkinter` so please remove that tag

Comment: the question (or problem) has also not much to do with python, maybe you should remove that tag too, and first learn SQL before learning python.

Comment: In stead of that picture, you also could have posted "ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Answer (score 1):

```
(equipmentID, name, available, borrowed,  total)
      ^         ^       ^          ^         ^
      1         2       3          4         5
```

```
(NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW())
  ^     ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
  1     2   3   4   5   6
```

Comment: You beat me to it

Comment: thanks, I just didn't think that NOW() is also a value

Answer (score 0):

- You have 5 columns in the command insert and you are passing 6 values
- If it’s auto increment, you don’t need to pass equipmentID
- You can automatically retrieve the date and save it.

```
ALTER TABLE Equipment MODIFY COLUMN createdDt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

```
query = "INSERT INTO Equipment(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES(NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW())"
cursor.execute(query, (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 ))
```

Comment: I guess you'd want to remove `NOW()` now